# Flask error when connecting to mysql using pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pymysql

So I am using pymysql to conenct mysql to flask. When I was developing a website on my local computer everything was fine, later when I uploaded my website to digital ocean trying to connect gives me an error:

> 'NoneType' object is not iterable

The view I get the error in:

```
@app.route('/test/') 
def test_page():
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        return("okay")
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

The connection file looks like this:

```
import pymysql

def connection():
    try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", passwd="my_password",db="db_name",charset='utf8')
        c = conn.cursor()
        return conn, c
    except Exception as e:
        print (str(e))
```

I am stuck with this problem for like couple of hours, cant find a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have the entire stack trace?

Comment: I am kind of new to the whole flask development thing so debuging isn't my strongest part and I can't find the whole stack trace.

Comment: Made few testing and found that: pymysql.err.InternalError: (1698, u"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")

Answer (score 0):

Your pymysql.connection is trying to connect to a database running on the local machine.

Evidently there is no database on your Digital Ocean server, or if there is it's not accessible on port 3306 with the credentials provided.

Comment: All the tutorials about setting up flask + mysql gives host to be localhost then enter credentials and enters database name. I already have removed the port, but still no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Found a mistake. All I need was a fresh reinstall of mysql :)